# Call a result of a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to bring out the results of a function that is within another function. When I try to print or return results it only brings out the result of the function "Sum".

```
let readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
let a = readlineSync.question(
"Choose an operation: Sum or Substraction: "
);
let param1 = parseInt(readlineSync.question("Value 1: "));
let param2 = parseInt(readlineSync.question("Value 2: "));
chosenFunction();

function Sum() {
    return param1 + param2;

}

function Substraction() {
    return param1 - param2;
}

function chosenFunction() {
    let result;
    if (a = 'Sum') {
        result = console.log (Sum());
    } else if (a = 'Substraction') {
        result = console.log ( Substraction());
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an invalid usage,when you assign value,you need to remove `console.log`

Also need to change `=` to `==` when compare values

So change

```
result = console.log (Sum());
result = console.log ( Substraction());
```

to

```
result = Sum();
result = Substraction();
```

Full code

```
function chosenFunction() {
    let result;
    if (a == 'Sum') {
        result = Sum();
    } else if (a == 'Substraction') {
        result = Substraction();
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` or `===`.  You are actually changing your values, not comparing, when using `=` as in `else if (a = 'Substraction')`.

```
if (a === 'Sum')
else if (a === 'Substraction')
```